# SQL: Report on whats not there

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that searches by month a error reason and the count of the error reason.

```
Select datepart(month,CL.[errorDate]) As Month,
ErrorReason As 'Errors'
Count(ErrorReason)
From ErrorTable
Group BY datepart(month,errorDate), ErrorReason
```

Which is fine. 
If I have 10 Error Reasons

```
Reason 1
Reason 2
Reason 3

... and so on
```

And one month there was no errors for Reason 2. Then it wouldn't return a result.

How can I change this query, so it would return the Month number, Error Reason but error count as 0

Thanks

Comment: How many months do you want to display?

Comment: What is the full table structure? Do you have a separate table which hold the Reasons

Comment: And if a month has no reasons at all? For example May 1838.

Comment: Hi, I want to display all months available of the year 2015.
Its one table that has a lot of different data, but two columns are DelDate & Error Reason. If it makes it easier, I can have a separate table that holds the ErrorReason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a date table for this.  Having a list of dates to join against gives you all the values you need, by providing a record for each month, regardless of the number of errors.

In this example I've created a date table on the fly, using a recursive CTE.  But a physical table would work just as well.  I've also created a second CTE with some sample data in it so anyone can run the example.

[Example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/402416/date-table-example)

```
DECLARE @StartMonth DATE = '2015-01-01';
DECLARE @EndMonth    DATE = '2015-03-01';

WITH SampleError AS
    (
        /* This CTE returns sample error records.
         * There are two entrie for Jan and Mar.
         * None for Feb.
         */
        SELECT
            r.ErrorDate,
            r.ErrorReason
        FROM
            (
                VALUES
                    ('2015-01-01', 1),
                    ('2015-01-02', 1),
                    ('2015-03-01', 1),
                    ('2015-03-02', 2)
            ) AS r(ErrorDate, ErrorReason)
    ),
    DateTable AS
    (
        /* This CTE creates a date table.
         * You could replace with with a 
         * real table.
         * It uses recurision to populate the rows.
         */
            SELECT
                @StartMonth        AS [Month]

        UNION ALL

            SELECT
                DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [Month])        AS [Month]
            FROM
                DateTable
            WHERE
                [Month] < @EndMonth
    )
SELECT
    dt.[Month],
    SUM(CASE WHEN se.ErrorReason = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)        AS Error1Count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN se.ErrorReason = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)        AS Error2Count
FROM
    DateTable AS dt
        LEFT OUTER JOIN SampleError AS se        ON    MONTH(se.ErrorDate)    = MONTH(dt.[Month])
                                                AND    YEAR(se.ErrorDate)    = YEAR(dt.[Month])
GROUP BY
    dt.[Month]
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.MonthName, r.ErrorReason,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM ErrorTable e2 
    WHERE datepart(month,e2.errorDate) = m.MonthName AND e2.ErrorReason = r.ErrorReason)
FROM (
    SELECT datepart(month,errorDate) As MonthName
    FROM ErrorTable
    GROUP BY datepart(month,errorDate)
) m CROSS JOIN
(   
    Select ErrorReason
    FROM ErrorTable
    GROUP BY ErrorReason
) r
```